# Merge two nd2 stacks in batch mode

Tags: imagej

I have a folder with following Nikon NIS files:

```
P00_S00.nd2
P00_S11.nd2
P01_S01.nd2
P01_S12.nd2
P02_S02.nd2
P02_S13.nd2
```

up to:

```
P10_S10.nd2
P10_S21.nd2
```

I'd like to concatenate them by P (position):

```
P00_S00.nd2 + P00_S11.nd2 = P00.nd2
P01_S01.nd2 + P01_S12.nd2 = P01.nd2
```

At the moment I have an ImageJ macro that requires the two files to be open:

```
pt = "P00"

win1 = pt + "_S00.nd2"
win2 = pt + "_S11.nd2"

selectWindow(win1);
selectWindow(win2);

run("Concatenate...", "  title=" + pt + " image1=" + win1 + " image2=" + win2 + " image3=[-- None --]");
saveAs("Tiff", "~/out/" + pt + ".tif");
```

How can I do it such that the entire folder is processed at once without opening files manually? Does ImageJ Macro have text parsing functions to extract iterators from filenames?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use the "Process Folder" script template, available from the Templates menu of ImageJ's Script Editor. For details, see:

- The [batch processing page](http://imagej.net/Batch) on the ImageJ wiki
- The [Scripting with Fiji workshop](http://imagej.github.io/presentations/fiji-scripting/#/4/1)